# Is there a way to compare memory consumption of rendering approaches involving virtual DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, frameworks

## React

As I know, React based on approach like this happening on update:
0) on every update anything recreated including functions declared in the function component, including the functions that are parameters of useState, setState or useEffect, and other hooks.

1. There are 2 versions of virtual dom ("current" and "new"). They both sit in memory during update flow.
2. After differences applied, the result becomes "current" version of virtual dom and previous version discarded (scheduled for eventual GC?)
3. The virtual dom applied to real dom.

## Alternative theory 1

What if instead this approach will be used:

1. single vdom (state tree) sit in memory
2. when change to state applied, propagated through state of children components, if any bindings to it inside children components properties,
3. new real dom created for changed components as changes applied to real dom inside requestAnimationFrame call

Reason for 3 is that it should allow to reduce flicking as all update to real dom would happen inside the requestAnimationFrame, "inivisible from user", and as outcome it will be less often, sorta auto-throttled process, and less of browser code will run during applying these updates, and actual composition will be fired after the requestAnimationFrame callback will be completed (I hope for that after all).

## Alternative Theory 2

Separate render and intitialize, like

```js
interface ComponentImplementation<TProps extends object, TState extends object> {
   initialize(props): TState;
   render(state:TState): VDomElement|(VDomElement[]);
}
```

## Theory 3

It is essentially combination of Theory 2 and scheduling of rendering as part of requestAnimationFrame

## Questions

What is better in terms of memory consumption?
Are there some experimental libraries implementing something like theories #1, #2, #3?